# calling adodb open changes connection string

Tags: vb.net, vb6, connection-string, adodb

I just got pulled into a project where we are converting old VB6 applications to .NET. Within the application they are passing around the ADODB connection object and grabbing the existing connection string from it (which could be a primary or secondary connection string depending on the status of the database).

The specific problem I am having is that sometimes when .open is called on the ADODB connection, the object resets it's connection string to some sort of ";Provider=MSDASQL.1". I have found one forum post that just states that the poster believes this to be some sort of bug in ADODB but can't find anything to confirm or any work around. Another thing to note is that the ConnectionString data is not always reset.

Has anyone seen this before and have a suggestion as to what is causing ADODB to reset its object's ConnectionString on the .Open call?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you see this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2010/05/28/why-is-my-connectionstring-incorrect.aspx ?

Comment: This seems to work. I appreciate you posting this. Thanks very much!

Comment: Wow, it seems pretty shabby to be trying to reuse a ConnectionString in that way. When set they are parsed into their components and used to set various properties, and when read a new value is fabricated based on current settings. This isn't a simple string-valued property. Hopefully your rewrite will change this poor practice but it sounds like it isn't going to.  Shouldn't you be migrating from ADO to ADO.Net anyway?

Comment: Bob - You are absolutely right and we want to rewrite this, but as of right now we're only commissioned to do a straight conversion with minor changes. We're putting together a proposal to change this behavior as well as some others.